# Groupby show max value and corresponding label - pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to group specific values and return the max value of a separate column. I'm also hoping to return the corresponding label this max value is associated with. Using below, I'm grouping values by `Item, Group, Direction` and the max value is determined from `Value`. I'm hoping to return the corresponding `Label` with the respective max in `Value`.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({  
    'Item' : [10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10],  
    'Label' : ['X','V','Y','Z','D','A','E','B','M'],    
    'Value' : [80.0,80.0,200.0,210.0,260.0,260.0,300.0,300.0,310.0],  
    'Group' : ['Red','Green','Red','Green','Red','Green','Green','Red','Green'],            
    'Direction' : ['Up','Up','Down','Up','Up','Up','Up','Down','Up'],                                       
    })

max_num = (df.groupby(['Item','Group','Direction'])['Value','Label']
                   .max()
                   .unstack([1, 2], 
                   fill_value = 0)
                   .reset_index()
                   )

max_num.columns = [f'{x[0]}_{x[1]}' for x in max_num.columns]
```

intended output:

```
   Item  Red_Up_Value Red_Up_ID  Red_Down_Value Red_Down_ID  Green_Up_Value Green_Up_ID  Green_Down_Value  Green_Down_ID
0    10         260.0         D           300.0           B           310.0           M               0.0            NaN
```

Comment: `df[df['Value'] == df['Value'].max()]['Label'].values[0]`Is this what you intend to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax.html) with [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) for `Labels` by maximal values and then reshape by [`DataFrame.pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html), added [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) for append all missing combinations, sorting `MultiIndex` and last flatten it:

```
max_num = (df.loc[df.groupby(['Item','Group','Direction'])['Value']
             .idxmax()]
            .pivot('Item', ['Direction','Group'], ['Value','Label'])
             .rename(columns={'Label':'ID'})
             )

max_num = max_num.reindex(pd.MultiIndex.from_product(max_num.columns.levels), axis=1)
max_num['Value'] = max_num['Value'].fillna(0)

max_num = max_num.sort_index(level=[2,1], axis=1, ascending=[True, False])
max_num.columns = [f'{x[2]}_{x[1]}_{x[0]}' for x in max_num.columns]
max_num = max_num.reset_index()
print (max_num)
   Item Green_Up_ID  Green_Up_Value  Green_Down_ID  Green_Down_Value  \
0    10           M           310.0            NaN               0.0   

  Red_Up_ID  Red_Up_Value Red_Down_ID  Red_Down_Value  
0         D         260.0           B           300.0
```

Comment: `.pivot_table`I'm getting a similar error as below. Apparently using `.pivot_table` instead of  `.pivot` is suggested. This works but `.sort_index` needs to be amended

Comment: @jonboy - OK, so need upgrade pandas, is it possible?

Comment: Yep, that worked. Only issue is inserting 0 and nan for missing values.

Answer (score 1):

Try with `Groupby.transform` and `df.pivot`:

```
In [270]: df['max_value'] = df.groupby(['Item','Group','Direction'])['Value'].transform('max')

In [279]: df[df.max_value.eq(df.Value)].pivot('Item', ['Group', 'Direction', 'Label'], 'Value')
Out[279]: 
Group        Red  Green    Red  Green
Direction     Up   Down   Down     Up
Label          D      A      B      M
Item                                 
10         260.0  260.0  300.0  310.0
```

Comment: I'm getting an error: `KeyError: 'Level Group not found'` on pivot

Comment: Check your column names. I've posted working code as per the sample df you provided.

Comment: Apologies, `.pivot` wasn't working but `pivot_table` did. I needed to upgrade pandas